# How to connect Bootstrap Studio with VSCode

Tags: vscode-extensions, bootstrap-studio

I want to connect VSCode to bootstrap srudio so that when I edit code it will redirect to VScode. I already added VSCode as an external editor but it is still opening in bootstrap studio.

Is there any way to open the code in vscode itself?